# 413 (Request Entity Too Large) when attempting to upload a file express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I have a simple POST to a `/upload` express endpoint. Small files work just fine, however, anything above 2mb gives me the following error:

> 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Is there something I am missing that needs to be added to work? Here is what my code looks like:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

router.post('/upload', fileUpload(), function (req, res) {
  console.log('I am never reached')
  let uploadFile = req.files.file
  const fileName = req.files.file.name
  // do stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss another middleware before that? I should also note that in `fileUpload`, I have tried to put as:

```
fileUpload({
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
})
```

But it didn't help. What else could be wrong?

Edit:  This is my fetch code in case that may also help:

```
  const data = new FormData()
  data.append('file', file, file.name)
  return isomorphicFetch(`/upload`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some hours trying to figure it out in my side.

Regardless the configuration that I was following the I always was getting the 413 as status code and I realized the problem was in NGINX Ingress in my kubernetes cluster, then I added:

```
  ...
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
```

This was enough to solve it.

I hope you it can help who else get this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in the main file of your application:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false, limit:'100mb',parameterLimit:1000000 }));
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference unfortunately.